# Remote file inclusion (RFI) found - vulnerability or false positive?

Tags: web-application, vulnerability, vulnerability-scanners, zap, vulnerability-assessment

For educational purposes, I am pentesting an app server of mine. I am using [ZAP](https://www.zaproxy.org/) and it reports a remote file inclusion vulnerability. I looked at it and think its a false positive but before I miss something I wanted to ask the community:

**ZAP Report:**

```
URL:        https://myapplication.net/home/logoff?target=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F
Method:     GET
Parameter:  target
Attack:     http://www.google.com/
Evidence:   <title>Google</title>
```

**Result**:
When executing the link I am forwarded to *oogle

**Question**
But how can this be an RFI? It might be an unchecked external redirect, ok but RFI? RFI for me is the injection of a malicious file and the execution of it - or what am I missing?

Update:
`curl -I` prints

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 03 Dec 2020 16:32:37 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.google.com/
Via: 1.1 someInternalServer1.net
Vary: User-Agent
Via: 1.1 someInternalServer2.net
```

Comment: What headers is sent? What does `curl -I https://myapplication.net/home/logoff?target=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F` provide?

Comment: Updated the question with the values

Comment: Have you tried running the ZAP Desktop vs your app? ZAP seems to have found a Google like title, so would be interesting to see whats shown in the response in ZAP.